# How to get filename of files stored in cloud storage and blobstore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

For an application, I have upload files on both blobstore and cloud storage.

I am doing that by generating upload links by this:

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name=app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
```

Files are saved on both blobstore and cloud storage, and I can perform GQL queries to retrieve any files I want from blobstore. However, I am unable to find a way to get the filename in cloud storage.

When files are uploaded in cloud storage, it is assigned a long filename automatically.

I found a command, but I am not sure how to use this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo

When I tried:

```
cloud_store = []
for upload in uploads:
     gcs_link = blobstore.BlobInfo(db.get(upload)).gs_object_name
     cloud_store.append(gcs_link)
```

Here `uploads` stores result of a GQL query performed on a kind that has `blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()` property.

I get this error:

```
BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<type 'basestring'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key'>); received <models.PhotoAlbum object at 0x00000000054CD7B8> (a PhotoAlbum).
```

When I tried:

```
cloud_store = []
for upload in uploads:
    gcs_link = blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.key()).gs_object_name
    cloud_store.append(gcs_link)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Must provide Entity or BlobKey
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `uploads` is a result of datastore query it means it contains a list of datastore entities (I assume it's not a keys_only query). So `upload` is one such entity, which contains the `blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()` property  (you didn't specify its name, let's assume it's called `blob_key`).

If so what you need to pass to `blobstore.BlobInfo()` needs to be the blob key, i.e. the `upload`'s datastore entity property, not the key of the entity itself. So I'd try (with the above assumption about the property name):

```
gcs_link = blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.blob_key).gs_object_name
```

Comment: That gives me error: `TypeError: Must provide Entity or BlobKey`. But, I found solution: `gcs_link = blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.blob_key.key()).gs_object_name`

Answer (score 1):

***GCS via Java:***

You need the Google Cloud Storage service Object which you can obtained from below a steps:

**A. Configure**

1. Configuration Input like `googleServiceAccountCredentials` and `projectId`

```
StorageOptions configureStorageOptions = 
StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).setCredentials(googleServiceAccountCredentials).build();
```

2. GCS service object via `configureStorageOptions` obtain from Step 1:

```
Storage getStorage = configureStorageOptions.getService();
```

Since from above code snippet you have Google Storage Object.

**B. Use case**

Here we will take an example that file uploaded to Google Storage inside bucket is based on `requestNumber` i.e. request number will be a directory in the Google Storage bucket.

So we must create path as shown in below code snippet:

```
String path = bucketName.concat("/").concat(requestNumber).concat("/");
```

**Note:**

1. Don't forget to append `/` as show in the above path.
2. Same `path` will be referred to in below code snippet.

Now you can refer the below code snippet for fetching File name from Google Storage Account:

**C. Code Snippet to fetch File Name from GCS**

```
List<String> supportingDocuments = new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
            log.info("Get FileName From Path {} With BucketName As {}", path, bucketName);
            Page<Blob> blobs = getStorage().list(bucketName, Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory(), Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(path));
            for (Blob blob:blobs.iterateAll()){
                String fileName = blob.getName().replace(path, "");
                supportingDocuments.add(fileName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**Note:**

1. `getStorage()` method is same which is mentioned `A. Configure` point 2 as ref `getStorage` i.e. `Storage` Java Object